# cant connect work laptop to home wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, thinkpad

i have a work laptop thats a ibm thinkpad. when i try to connect to home wireless it connects but then hangs on "waiting for ip configuration"...finally it just drops the connection.

I can get my other laptop to connect to my wireless router w/out any problem.

what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Powercycle both the laptop and the wireless AP/router
- Unplug (power off) any nearby 2.4ghz cordless phones
- Change the wireless mode on your home AP/router from B+G mode to B only

Also, do you get an IP if you plug directly into your router via Ethernet?